# How to use ng class inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have a template where I loop to display data contained in json file ( I use json server ), the problem I encounter is that I can't use ng class correctly.
When I click on my icon, it adds a scss class, but it applies it to all my icons at the same time. I can't figure out how to make it so that when I click on my first element, the scss class applies only to it.

thanks.

**html**

```
<div class="image-mosaic">
      <div class="card" *ngFor="let film of films">
            <img [src]="film.img" class="img-style">
            <div class="icon-style">
                <mat-icon (click)="addFavoris(film); $event.stopPropagation()" [ngClass]="{'rouge': film.favoris == true}">
                    favorite_border
                </mat-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**ts**

```
export class TemplateListComponent {
  public showFiller = false;
  @Input() public films: MovieListe[];
  @Output() public favoris = new EventEmitter();

  addFavoris(favoris: MovieListe) {
    this.showFiller = !this.showFiller;

    let t: MovieListe = { ...favoris };
    t.favoris = this.showFiller;

    this.favoris.emit(t);
  }
}
```

**json**

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Smile",
      "rating": 2,
      "releaseDate": "12/02/2010",
      "img": "assets/img/film.jpg",
      "favoris": true
    },
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to add a class to an icon when click on it?

Comment: yes, but not for all other icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add class to the element you just clicked, you can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-mosaic">
      <div class="card" *ngFor="let film of films">
            <img [src]="film.img" class="img-style">
            <div class="icon-style">
                <mat-icon (click)="addClass(icon)" #icon>
                    favorite_border
                </mat-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
export class TemplateListComponent {
  public showFiller = false;
  @Input() public films: MovieListe[];
  @Output() public favoris = new EventEmitter();

  public addClass(element: MatIcon): void {
    element._elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('your class');
  }
  
}
```